# using regex inside keybindings.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to use regex inside of the text in args,

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text":'${file}.'\u000D"  } 
}
```

I want to take the name of the file from the file path using this regex - `^\\(.+\\)*(.+)\.(.+)$`
or taking the filename in other way,
anyone can help?:)

Comment: why add `^` and `$` to the regex, that means match the whole string, give an example of what you want, file path of the editor file and file path you want in the terminal command, your json is also incorrect (quotes, double quotes) json does not use quotes

Comment: '/Users/yardeno/Documents/QA-clip/clip/test/checkout/tax/chile.spec.ts' - filepath, what I want in my terminal commad - chile.spec.ts

Comment: and what do you want in the key binding, the whole file path or a section, and also **fix** your json example, edit the question

Comment: and as for the json - it works perfectly, just don't know how to use regex in it

Comment: I want just the section above ☝️ @rioV8

Comment: the json works fine for me in the keybindings - it's copy paste from a working section of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a regexp, you want to use a different variable:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+r",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "'${fileBasename}'"  } 
}
```

See [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables).